# URL not resolving correctly in Django URL

Tags: django, django-models

I just tried the following in my AJAX update:

[Server]/secTypes/Update

This maps to the following url in URLS.py:

```
     url(r'^secTypes/Update/', equity.views.updateSecTypes,   name='updateSecTypes'),
```

This doesn't resolve to the following function in my view.

But when I change the URL expression to:

```
      url(r'^su/', equity.views.updateSecTypes, name='updateSecTypes')
```

It works fine.

What in the URL resolver is not getting accurately mapped? Is it the forward slash?

I think it has to do with something related to the regex so if someone understands this better can help me that would be appreciated.

Comment: URL paths are case sensitive, did you use the URL exactly as is? Also, your URL does define the forward slash, so if you have `APPEND_SLASH = False` in your settings, it won't work. Try accessing `/secTypes/Update/`.

Comment: Yes. It was the right case. I don't have the APPEND_SLASH as false. It's not in my settings. Any other thoughts?

Comment: You need to show the rest of the urls. Probably another pattern is catching your url.

Comment: url(r'^secTypes/', equity.views.getSecTypes, name='getSecTypes'),
    url(r'^secTypesAll/', equity.views.getSecTypesAll, name='getSecTypesAll'),
    url(r'^secTypes/Update/', equity.views.updateSecTypes, name='updateSecTypes'),
    url(r'^secTypes/Delete/', equity.views.deleteSecTypes, name='deleteSecTypes'),
    url(r'^secTypes/Create/', equity.views.createSecTypes, name='createSecTypes'),

Comment: When you mention it didn't resolve to your function, did you mean you got a 404 or it resolved to a different view?

Comment: I get a Status 200 but it returns the entire page back. In other words, it doesn't hit the view at the URL function (equity.views.updateSecTypes)

Comment: @Axwack Ah I thought it was a 404 since it wasn't clear from your original question. Now it's clear that it's actually resolving to the wrong pattern, please see my answer for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the url patterns in your comments, it looks like you had another matching pattern before the one in your question.

There are two simple solution for this.

---

1. Move that first pattern down. Change this:

   ```
   url(r'^secTypes/', equity.views.getSecTypes, name='getSecTypes'),
   url(r'^secTypesAll/', equity.views.getSecTypesAll, name='getSecTypesAll'),
   url(r'^secTypes/Update/', equity.views.updateSecTypes, name='updateSecTypes'),
   url(r'^secTypes/Delete/', equity.views.deleteSecTypes, name='deleteSecTypes'),
   url(r'^secTypes/Create/', equity.views.createSecTypes, name='createSecTypes'),
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   url(r'^secTypesAll/', equity.views.getSecTypesAll, name='getSecTypesAll'),
   url(r'^secTypes/Update/', equity.views.updateSecTypes, name='updateSecTypes'),
   url(r'^secTypes/Delete/', equity.views.deleteSecTypes, name='deleteSecTypes'),
   url(r'^secTypes/Create/', equity.views.createSecTypes, name='createSecTypes'),
   url(r'^secTypes/', equity.views.getSecTypes, name='getSecTypes'),
   ```

   The order matters when resolving URL patterns and if an earlier one matches, the following ones are not processed.

   Both `r'^secTypes/'` and `r'^secTypes/Update/'` matches the string `'secTypes/Update/'` so you need to be careful to put the more specific one first and the more general one afterwards.

---

2. Update the regex to match the end of the URL string by adding a `$` like this:

   ```
   url(r'^secTypes/$', equity.views.getSecTypes, name='getSecTypes'),
   url(r'^secTypesAll/$', equity.views.getSecTypesAll, name='getSecTypesAll'),
   url(r'^secTypes/Update/$', equity.views.updateSecTypes, name='updateSecTypes'),
   url(r'^secTypes/Delete/$', equity.views.deleteSecTypes, name='deleteSecTypes'),
   url(r'^secTypes/Create/$', equity.views.createSecTypes, name='createSecTypes'),
   ```

   This is the preferred solution since it would stop Django from matching a URL like `secTypes/Update/foobar`

   However, if you have logic in the view that specifically uses the substring after the end of the URL pattern (i.e. `foobar` based on the above example), this wouldn't work.

Comment: You are correct! Thank you for your help. This was the reason.

Comment: Great! I would suggest the 2nd solution if you only need to match the exact URL (this is true for most simple use cases).

Comment: In a past iteration, I think I did this and it didn't work (adding $ at the end).